# I have added a TrustKit.xcframework into my SDK project which is in Swift but when I am trying to use my SDK into my demo swift project

Tags: ios, xcode14, trustkit

Added a TrustKit.xcframework into my SDK project which is in Swift but when I am trying to use my SDK into my demo swift project through development pods,it’s giving below error.

dyld[62372]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit'
Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp .app/Frameworks/MyTestApp_SDK.framework/MyTestApp_SDK'

Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/MyTestApp_SDK.framework/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/557A6D2C-8510-4983-A680-471531A2B66C/MyTestApp Test.app/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/TrustKit.framework/TrustKit' (no such file)

https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-add-xcframework-to-xcode-project/

Also tried to add TrustKit folder path to library search paths & framework search paths in my SDK project